# MySql query don't work

Tags: php, mysql

What's wrong with this query?

$a-$o is normal, echo work

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `Zakazes` (
`id`, `dateDelivery`, `timeCok`, `nameClient`, `phoneClient`, `metro`,
 `adress`, `comments`, `product`, `summ`, `skidka`, `result`, `cupon`, 
`cuponPin`, `cuponBron`, `timeDelivery`) VALUES (\'NULL\', \'$a\', \'$b\',
 \'$c\', \'$d\', \'$e\', \'$f\', \'$g\', \'$h\', \'$i\', \'$j\', \'$k\',
 \'$l\', \'$m\', \'$n\', \'$o\');";
```

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO `Zakazes` (id, dateDelivery, timeCok, nameClient, phoneClient, metro,adress, comments, product, summ, skidka, result, cupon, 
cuponPin, cuponBron, timeDelivery) VALUES ('NULL', $a, $b,$c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j, $k,$l, $m, $n, $o);";

Comment: @Anant Does the `;` after `)` should be removed ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No need to have `''` for the table column , it's needed for the variable that need to be inserted into the table column.

Between, remove the `;` after `)`.

The correct code should be looked like this:

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO Zakazes(
    id, dateDelivery, timeCok, nameClient, phoneClient, metro,
     adress, comments, product, summ, skidka, result, cupon, 
    cuponPin, cuponBron, timeDelivery) VALUES ('NULL', '$a', '$b',
     '$c', '$d', '$e', '$f', '$g', '$h', '$i', '$j', '$k',
     '$l', '$m', '$n', '$o')";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: thanks..explaination included.